# Eigenvalues of Matrix Used in the Context of Bilinear Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bilinear-form

Doing an exercise on Matrices.

I am asked to find the rank of the quadratic form $2xy+2yz+2zx$ over $\mathbb R$. I understand that you need to find a diagonal matrix congruent to
$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$
but when I look at the solution it talks about the eigenvalues of this matrix.

What I don't understand is why we are interested in the eigenvalues, since we are looking at the matrix in the context of bilinear forms, as opposed to looking at it as an endomorphism.

So what is the connection here?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr    The fact to be used is Sylvester's Law of Inertia: call your matrix $H,$   if we construct invertible $P$  such that $P^T HP = D$  is diagonal, the count of positive eigenvalues of $H$ is the same as the count of positive elements of $D.$   Analogous for zero eigenvalues and zeroelements on the diagonal of $D$

Comment: Congruence is $P^tAP=B$. Similarity is $P^{-1}AP=B$. For $A$ symmetric, it is diagonalizable with $P$ orthogonal. $P$ orthogonal says $P^{-1}=P^t$.